# Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers: James 3:1

Tags: james

What did the disciple James mean when he said:  " Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers and sisters, because you know that we will be judged more strictly  ".James 3:1NET

Comment: This is just a comment - in my mind he is simply stating that there is a lot to lose if you get the teaching wrong and as such this position of teacher should be reserved to a limited number of very dedicated and serious individuals who are filled with the Holy Spirit. Not something to be taken lightly.

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo : Not so, At Matt.20: 19-20  Jesus commanded his disciples to “make disciples of people of all the nations. Hence, all Christians should be teachers. The apostle Paul counseled Hebrew Christians because they were not yet teachers.-Read Hebrews 5:12 
Was James telling qualified Christian men that they should not accept the role of teacher for fear of God’s heavier judgment? By no means. The office of elder is a great privilege, as indicated by 1 Timothy 3:1,

Answer (score 2):

James 3:1 is consistent with the instruction of Luke 12:48 -

> That servant who knows his master’s will but does not get ready or
> follow his instructions will be beaten with many blows. But the one
> who unknowingly does things worthy of punishment will be beaten with
> few blows. From everyone who has been given much, much will be
> required; and from him who has been entrusted with much, even more
> will be demanded.

That is, James 3:1 is simply repeating, in a slightly different form, what Jesus taught.  If one presumes to be a teacher then one must be informed and thus is more knowledgeable about spiritual truth.  Thus, such a person is judged more severely or strictly, or to a higher standard.

There is a similar message in the parable of the talents (Matt 25:14-30) and Jesus' teaching to the scribes and Pharisees (Matt 23:14).

Ellicott observes:

> **The greater condemnation**.—Rather, the greater judgment—more strictly searching and severe. “None of us liveth to himself, and no
> man dieth to himself” (Romans 14:7), and, if this be true of common
> Christian life, how deep is the responsibility incurred in the attempt
> to teach others!

The Cambridge commentary has something similar:

> **knowing that we shall receive the greater condemnation** The change from the second person to the first is characteristic of the writer’s
> profound humility. He will not give others a warning without at the
> same time applying it to himself. The Greek word for “condemnation”,
> though literally meaning “judgment” only, is yet almost always used in
> the New Testament for an adverse judgment, (e. g. Matthew 23:14;
> Romans 2:2; Romans 13:2; 1 Corinthians 11:29; 1 Corinthians 11:34).
> The very form of St James’s phrase is as an echo of our Lord’s words
> in the first of the passages referred to.